# Listas desplegables Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

estoy intentando hacer una interfaz en Shiny de R, la idea es seleccionar un archivo .csv, al leerlo tomar las columnas y ponerlas en una lista desplegable

Lo he intentado de varias maneras, de momento parece que lee el archivo, pero no actualiza la lista desplegable, alguna idea de que pueda esta pasando?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui = fluidPage(
theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
navbarPage(theme = "flatly","Analisis de Datos",
           tabPanel("Analisis Exploratorio")),
sidebarPanel(
fileInput("archivo", "Escoger archivo CSV",multiple = TRUE, accept = 
c("text/csv","text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",".csv")),
tabPanel("Histograma",
selectInput("columnas", "Seleccionar Columna", choices= NULL))))


 server <-function(input, output , session) {
 Datos <- reactive({
   inFile <- input$archivo
   req(inFile)
   # Leyendo el csv 
   df <- read.csv(input$archivo$datapath,header = TRUE,sep =',',quote = '"')
   #Nombre de las columnas
   variables <- names(df)
   updateSelectInput(session, "columnas", "Seleccionar Columna", choices = 
   variables)
   return(df)   

})
    }
   shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Para que te funcione tal como estás construyendo la interfaz deberías incorporar un "output", sin él no tiene sentido un `reactive`, podrías hacer algo así:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
    navbarPage(theme = "flatly","Analisis de Datos", tabPanel("Analisis Exploratorio")),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput("archivo", "Escoger archivo CSV",multiple = TRUE, accept = 
                          c("text/csv","text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",".csv")),
            tabPanel("Histograma",
                     selectInput("columnas", "Seleccionar Columna", choices= NULL))
        ),
        mainPanel(
            uiOutput("tb")
        )
    )
))

server <-function(input, output , session) {
    data <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$archivo
        req(inFile)
        df <- read.csv(input$archivo$datapath,header = TRUE,sep =',',quote = '"')
        #Nombre de las columnas
        variables <- names(df)
        updateSelectInput(session, "columnas", "Seleccionar Columna", choices = variables)
        return(df)          
    })

    output$table <- renderTable({
        if(is.null(data())){return ()}
        data()    
    })

    output$tb <- renderUI({
        if(is.null(data()))
            h5("Sin datos")
        else
            tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Datos", tableOutput("table")))
    })    
}
```

Incorporamos un `mainPanel` dónde dibujaremos la salida que no va a ser otra cosa que un `tableOutput` del archivo `csv`, solo como ejemplo, en tu caso seguramente será otra cosa, lo que si es fundamental es tener un `output` para que funciones el `reactive` de **Shinny**. Sino, también se puede implementar mediante `observe`, de la siguiente forma:

```
server <-function(input, output , session) {

    observe({
        inFile <- input$archivo
        req(inFile)
        df <- read.csv(input$archivo$datapath,header = TRUE,sep =',',quote = '"')
        #Nombre de las columnas
        variables <- names(df)
        updateSelectInput(session, "columnas", "Seleccionar Columna", choices = variables)
        return(df)          
    })
}
```